# ninja output empty compdb content

Tags: android-source, ninja

When i tried to integrate `Google Kythe` system with my own Android source code.
And i found i need to generate `compile_commands.json` first.

So i run command `prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/ninja -f out/combined-$target.ninja -t compdb`, however generate nothing.

```
$ prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/ninja -f out/combined-venus.ninja -t compdb
[
]
```

And my version of ninja:

```
$ prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/ninja --version
1.8.2.git
```

I also created a Helloworld project to do the samething, yet still nothing. Is it a known issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it seems only latest ninja process could generate the json file.
so i download from github and compile ninja myself. now it works